# Problem with enable and disable a dropdownlist using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

My HTML code

```
Transportation:
<input type="radio" name="transportation" value="BUS">  Bus </option><br>
<input type="radio" name="transportation" id="khaschkbox" value="KHAS">Khas</option><br>

Bus:
<select id="busDropdown" name="bus">
      <option value="Null"> NA </option>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT busNumber FROM Bus";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row_count = $result->rowCount();
    if ($row_count > 0){
    while ($row = $result->fetch())
      {
        echo "<option value=".$row['busNumber'].">".$row['busNumber']."</option>";
      }
    }
    ?>
    </select><br><br>
```

in my jQuery, if the user checked Khas, the dropdown list will be disabled. that works. but the problem if the user chose khas then Bus the dropdownlist will remain disabled which is wrong!

JQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(function() {
          $("#khaschkbox").change(function(){
            if(this.checked){
              $("#busDropdown").prop("disabled",true);
            } else {
              $("#busDropdown").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            });
        });
```

I need the list to appear when the user choose Bus and disappear if he chose Khas. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this : -

```
$(function() {
      $('[name="transportation"]').click(function(){
        if(this.value !== 'BUS'){
          $("#busDropdown").prop("disabled",true);
        } else {
          $("#busDropdown").prop("disabled",false);
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Well, yes, the change event is only fine with select tag, so you need to target the radio group to see what is selected....Cheers!!!

Comment: I see now, Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {

var khaschkbox = $('#khaschkbox');
          $('input[name="transportation"]').change(function(){
            if(khaschkbox.is( ":checked" )){
              $("#busDropdown").attr("disabled","disabled");
            } else
              $("#busDropdown").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Still the same problem :( could that be from my included library? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: great. Thank you!